# PdfClown nullpointer on Font access

Tags: java, pdfclown

I have something strange going on with text writing using PdfClown 0.1.2.

```
PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);
    BlockComposer blockComposer = new BlockComposer(composer);
    addHeader(document, composer, blockComposer);
    addOfferData(document, offer, blockComposer, composer);
    composer.flush();

private void addHeader(Document document, PrimitiveComposer composer, BlockComposer blockComposer) {
    Rectangle2D frame = new Rectangle2D.Double(36, 0, 842, 36);
    blockComposer.begin(frame, XAlignmentEnum.Left, YAlignmentEnum.Middle);
    composer.setFont(getSimpleFont(document), 12);
    blockComposer.showText(getHeader());
    blockComposer.end();
}

private void addOfferData(Document document, Offer offer, BlockComposer blockComposer, PrimitiveComposer composer) {
    blockComposer.begin(new Rectangle2D.Double(456, 156, 340, 250), XAlignmentEnum.Left, YAlignmentEnum.Top);
    composer.setFont(getSimpleFont(document), 12);

        blockComposer.showText("Text");
        blockComposer.showBreak();

    blockComposer.end();
}

    private StandardType1Font getSimpleFont(Document document) {
    return new StandardType1Font(document, StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Times, false, false);
}
```

In JUnit test everything is ok, but in production mode it is failing in the second method, on showText.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.encode(Font.java:423)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition.PrimitiveComposer.showText(PrimitiveComposer.java:1058)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition.PrimitiveComposer.showText(PrimitiveComposer.java:960)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition.BlockComposer.showText(BlockComposer.java:553)
    at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition.BlockComposer.showText(BlockComposer.java:463)
    at com.example.service.PdfGenerationService.addOfferData(PdfGenerationService.java:121)
```

Does the font needs to be handled somehow differently, or what could cause this problem? In the first method text is being rendered what is the strangest here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` occurs at `Font.encode(Font.java:423)`. This method is:

```
public final byte[] encode(
    String text
    )
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream encodedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        for(int index = 0, length = text.length(); index < length; index++)
        {
            int textCode = text.charAt(index);
            byte[] charCode = codes.getKey(textCode).data;
            encodedStream.write(charCode);
            usedCodes.add(textCode);
        }
        encodedStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {throw new RuntimeException(e);}

    return encodedStream.toByteArray();
}
```

> *([Font.java](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/tags/0.1.2-Beta/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/fonts/Font.java) revision 85, lines 413..433)*

Line 423 is

```
            byte[] charCode = codes.getKey(textCode).data;
```

Thus, either `codes` is `null` or `codes.getKey(textCode)` is `null.`

The former (`codes` being `null`) is pretty implausible for a `StandardType1Font`.

The latter (`codes.getKey(textCode)` being `null`) would mean that the text to draw contains characters not present in the encoding at hand.

Assuming that in production you do not call

```
blockComposer.showText("Text");
```

but instead use some different production text, you should check that text for special characters (probably not present in standard PDF encodings).

If that assumption is wrong and you indeed in production only show `"Text"`, more analysis of the differences production environment <-> development environment is required.

Comment: Yes, the problem was special characters. Instead of SimpleFont I am using fonts from outside.

Comment: You might want to inform the pdfclown author... a `NullPointerException` in such a situation is not appropriate, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @mkl In accordance with your wise suggestion, the latest commit for PDF Clown 0.1.2.1 includes a customizable fallback mechanism for properly dealing with missing characters (here's the announcement: https://twitter.com/PDFClown/status/587798095615885312).

Comment: @mkl Such fallback mechanism can 1) silently ignore those characters, 2) automatically substitute them with default, or 3) throw a specific informative exception (EncodeException/DecodeException), at user's will (see Document.Configuration.EncodingFallback property).

Comment: That sounds great. Let's hope people read the doc before running into that issue ;)